# Error Loading Extensions in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I have installed jupyter notebook nbextensions in my environment. When i am trying to enable some features in the extensions tab. i am getting the error like these for all the extensions avaiable-

`[jupyter_nbextensions_configurator] error loading hinterland/hinterland [jupyter_nbextensions_configurator] error loading jupyter_tabnine/main [jupyter_nbextensions_configurator] error loading skill/main [jupyter_nbextensions_configurator] error loading help_panel/help_panel`
etc.,

I tried to uninstall the jupyter nbextensions and tried insalling again but the issue is still there.

[1]Jupyter notebook extension error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOxqs.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and the one thing that worked for me was downgrading nbclassic to version 0.4.8 (as per the instructions [here](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/1628#issuecomment-1455433834)).